# Google Webmaster Tools gets 301 Redirect incorrectly

Tags: apache2, http-status-code-301, redirect, http-redirect, google-search-console

In Google Webmaster Tools, I tell Google to crawl and render my site:

Inlcuding:
http://smartnavi-app.com/download

Google shows me its HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 07:24:56 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.2
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Location: http://smartnavi-app.com/index.html
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

**But there should be NO redirect for that URL!**

If I open this URL I am correctly not redirected. So why is Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I am using prerender.io to cache my AJAX Website for Crawler-Bots.
In the .htaccess my Domain in the prerender.io part was an old one, so there was kind of a redirect loop.
So if you change redirects etc. never forget your prerender.io stuff!